# Powershell - Delete excel rows that contain a word

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm really new to Powershell and I feel like I've looked all over and can't quite figure out what is wrong with my code.

My goal is a powershell script that can run against an Excel workbook and delete rows with a specific string in the cell (in this case it is local admin accounts).

Currently my script launches the excel sheet opens, but no rows are deleted. The code exits without error. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
$ObjExcelCellTypeLastCell = 11

$ObjExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$ObjExcel.Visible = $True
$ObjExcel.DisplayAlerts = $True
$Workbook = $ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("File\Path\") 
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$used = $Worksheet.usedRange
$lastCell = $used.SpecialCells($ObjExcelCellTypeLastCell)
$row = $lastCell.row

for ($i = $Worksheet.usedrange.rows.count; $i -gt 0; $i--)
 {
    If ($Worksheet.Cells.Item($i, 1) = "Local Admin") {
        $Range = $Worksheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).EntireRow
        $Range.Delete()
        $i = $i + 1

    Else 
    Break
    }
Exit
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about powershell but i think your if statement `$Worksheet.Cells.Item($i, 1) = "Local Admin"` is wrong, you should use `-eq`
also maybe you need to call the  `Close` method on the workbook object that you just `Open`'d

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's solved, but my code is like below. It's not exactly same to mine, but I think this would work.

```
#get last row
$rowLast = $WorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
#for loop
for ($row = $rowLast; $row -gt 0; $row--) {
    if($WorkSheet.Cells.Item($row, 1).Text -eq "Local Admin"){
        #delete the row. Without "[void]", you will get message "True" when successfully deleted the row.
        [void]$WorkSheet.Rows($row).Delete()
    }
}
```

I think you need ".Text" after "$Worksheet.Cells.Item($i, 1)".
Also, I think following codes should be removed.

```
$i = $i + 1

    Else 
    Break
Exit
```